# Memory leak in linked list

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

```
//==========set method===================
   Node *temp = new Node(data, i, j, NULL, NULL);
   addNode(temp, this->rowsArr[i], true);
   addNode(temp, this->colsArr[j], false);
}
//==============================================================
void SMatrix::addNode(Node *temp, Node *&list, bool colOrRow) {
    //check if the list is empty.
    if (list == NULL)
        list = temp;
    else {
        //true means rows array.
        if (colOrRow == true) {
            //check if the new node needs to be in the first place of the list. 
            if (list->colIndex > temp->colIndex) {
                temp->nextInRow = list;
                list = temp;
                return;
            }

            for (Node *p = list; p != NULL; p = p->nextInRow) {
                if (p->nextInRow == NULL) {
                    p->nextInRow = temp;
                    return;
                }
                if (p->nextInRow->colIndex > temp->colIndex) {
                    temp->nextInRow = p->nextInRow;
                    p->nextInRow = temp;
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
        //false means column array.
        else if (colOrRow == false) {
            //check if the new node needs to be in the first place of the list. 
            if (list->rowIndex > temp->rowIndex) {
                temp->nextInCol = list;
                list = temp;
                return;
            }

            for (Node *p = list; p != NULL; p = p->nextInCol) {
                if (p->nextInCol == NULL) {
                    p->nextInCol = temp;
                    return;
                }
                if (p->nextInCol->rowIndex > temp->rowIndex) {
                    temp->nextInCol = p->nextInCol;
                    p->nextInCol = temp;
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The code above is adding a node for matrix (that contains two arrays-rows and cols, and each cell contain linked-list of Nodes).
The code works fine for me, but I have a memory leak from the "set method" (from `Node* temp`, as you can guess), and if I delete `temp` (or free the temp) after the adding, I get segmentation fault. Any help?

Comment: You can not delete temp because your linked lists point to the same location. I say your leak is not in the code that you posted. Does your destructor for your matrix class free all nodes exactly 1 time (since each node is in 2 lists)?

Comment: If you delete the nodes in the list sooner or later, there won't be any leak. Also, I highly recommend you to not create your own lists unless it's a requirement (like a school assignment), use one of the [standard containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) instead. If you need special business requirements for the ordering, you can keep the container sorted using some custom comparator.

Answer (score 0):

`SMatrix::addNode` does not seem to have a problem, but you insert `temp` into 2 different lists:

```
Node *temp = new Node(data, i, j, NULL, NULL);
addNode(temp, this->rowsArr[i], true);
addNode(temp, this->colsArr[j], false);
```

If you `delete temp`, the nodes inserted in the lists will become invalid, and dereferencing them invokes undefined behavior.

If you remove and delete the node from one list and not from the other, same thing.

The problem is in the handling of the object lifetime.  Java would help you with the garbage collector, C++ does not have that. To avoid multiple deletes of the same node, you either need to:

- know exactly what is happening, for example always delete the `rowsArr[]` lists and reset the `colsArr[]` lists without deleting their elements.
- or duplicate the nodes, the simplest approach, assuming you do not need the sharing semantics.
- or purposely never delete any nodes.  This may or may not be a problem depending on how long your program runs and what it does with these lists.
- or use reference counts to determine when to finalize the node. Smart pointers are a handy way to achieve this.

Comment: The solution to avoid double delete: don't use `delete`... :-/ Unfortunately so true... memleak instead...

Comment: Avoiding `delete` does not imply memory leaks. Just use an appropriate smart pointer.

Comment: @Puppy: I was referring to the 3rd point *"purposely never delete any nodes"*. I agree that we may avoid raw `new`/`delete` with smart pointers :).